# Storing JSON as key value pair

Tags: mysql, json, database, data-structures

My question is how to store a nested JSON as key value in mysql table. Earlier I thought of storing it as CSV but on deep diving I found it like it would be difficult to query those values and to manage as well.
Please help me in giving alternate solutions of how and where to store JSON.

The version of MySQL I am using does not support the JSON data type

Comment: please share some example json along with some expected behaviour

Comment: @Rits perhaps you could store it as text, since ... that's how it's designed

Comment: For example:{"id":"1","name":"Peter","mobno":"+91 4567","parentinfo":{"Mname":"Alexia","FName":"Mary","FOccptn":"Buisnessman","mno":"+91 567876789"},"city":"CA"} My doubt is how to store parentinfo value in mysql database. Can we do it in mysql or we need to change the database as well?

Comment: The traditional way to do this would be to create objects out of the JSON and store each one individually as rows in their own table and to create foreign keys to relate them.  It should be relatively easy to serialize/deserialize your objects as JSON

Comment: There are many ways, but I think you are dealing with bad data design. SQL servers are mostly designed for pre-designed structures. yes, lots of work has been done on JSON or HSTORE etc. Think twice before you do so. Look at other DB engines more suitable for your use case. Go back to drawing board and ask WHY?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.7, you can store ans query JSON objects. Look at [this link](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-lab-release-json-functions-part-2-querying-json-data/) for more details and examples.

Comment: I am using older version of mysql and I am not going to upgrade it. Please share your answer keeping older version of mysql in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 5.7  a native JSON data type is supported.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

If your MySQL version is lower the only option left is to store it as text. Otherwise you will not be able to store it in a simple key value pair manner.

Comment: But the problem in saving as text is it will not be easy for querying up of data

Comment: That's right, but you want it to store it as key value pair, right?

Comment: Correct. But I want to store complete nested JSON as value. How to achieve this?

Comment: Assumptions: 1. Store as key value pair. 2. Query key values of the JSON data 3. The max length of the JSON is undefined. If all assumptions are true the only option is to use text. Your table will have two columns 'key: numeric' and 'value: text'. You will use the key as identifier and the text column for your JSON data. Other solutions will not end to a key value storage.